# Javascript generate array from given array using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Let's say I had an API call, which gives me result in three objects.

Example data, which i generated is here: https://pastebin.com/TSPLP8yf

How would i go into generating a full array list in javascript?

```
function generateNewSectorList(sectors, newList) {

    for (var i = 0; i < sectors.length; i++){
        var obj = sectors[i];
        newList.push(obj);
        if (hasChildren(obj)) {
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.Children.length; j++) {
                newList = generateNewSectorList(obj.Children[j], newList);
            }
        }

    }

    return newList;
}
```

This is where I am right now.

This is first initialized with data on that pastebin link and empty array ( [] ).

Function hasChildren is following:

```
    function hasChildren(obj) {
    if (obj.Children.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the end i need that list to be so that whenever there is a children element, it's name should have an extra `&nbsp;` in front of it compared to it's parent.

The elements are sorted in correct order already on the backend.

Reason for using recursion is that right now there is 3 layers of elements: Parent, Children and GrandChildren, but I would like the application work even, when there is 4 or more layers.

If there were no fourth layer I would not go with recursion, and just have three for-cycles inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"In the end i need that list to be so that whenever there is a children element, it's name should have an extra `&nbsp;` in front of it compared to it's parent."*

All you need to do is pass in a string, and add to it on each recursive call.

*EDIT: I missed that you were handling the recursion incorrectly. The function expects an array, so that's what you need to pass. No need for the inner loop.*

```
function generateNewSectorList(sectors, newList, indent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sectors.length; i++){
        var obj = sectors[i];

        // I guess this is where you want the indentation?
        obj.Name = indent + obj.Name;

        newList.push(obj);

        if (hasChildren(obj)) {
            newList = generateNewSectorList(
                          obj.Children,
                          newList,
                          indent + "&nbsp;" // Increase the indentation
                        );
            }
        }

    }

    return newList;
}
```

So then the first call will pass an empty string, or whatever amount of indentation you want to start with.

```
generateNewSectorList(data, [], "");
```

---

Here's a demo:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  const res = generateNewSectorList(data, [], "");
  res.forEach(obj => div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", obj.Name + "<br>"))
}, 100);


function generateNewSectorList(sectors, newList, indent) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sectors.length; i++) {
    var obj = sectors[i];

    // I guess this is where you want the indentation?
    obj.Name = indent + obj.Name;

    newList.push(obj);

    if (hasChildren(obj)) {
      newList = generateNewSectorList(
        obj.Children,
        newList,
        indent + "&nbsp;" // Increase the indentation
      );
    }

  }

  return newList;
}

function hasChildren(obj) {
  if (obj.Children.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


var data = [{
    "Children": [{
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 4,
        "Name": "Construction materials",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 5,
        "Name": "Electronics and Optics",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 23,
            "Name": "Bakery & confectionery products",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 24,
            "Name": "Beverages",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 25,
            "Name": "Fish & fish products",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 26,
            "Name": "Meat & meat products",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 27,
            "Name": "Milk & dairy products",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 28,
            "Name": "Other (Food)",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 29,
            "Name": "Sweets & snack food",
            "ParentSectorId": 6
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 6,
        "Name": "Food and Beverage",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 30,
            "Name": "Bathroom/sauna",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 31,
            "Name": "Bedroom",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 32,
            "Name": "Children’s room",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 33,
            "Name": "Kitchen",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 34,
            "Name": "Living room",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 35,
            "Name": "Office",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 36,
            "Name": "Other (Furniture)",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 37,
            "Name": "Outdoor",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 38,
            "Name": "Project furniture",
            "ParentSectorId": 7
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 7,
        "Name": "Furniture",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 39,
            "Name": "Machinery components",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 40,
            "Name": "Machinery equipment/tools",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 41,
            "Name": "Manufacture of machinery",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 42,
            "Name": "Maritime",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 43,
            "Name": "Aluminium and steel workboats",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 44,
            "Name": "Boat/Yacht building",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 45,
            "Name": "Ship repair and conversion",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 46,
            "Name": "Metal structures",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 47,
            "Name": "Other (Machinery)",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 48,
            "Name": "Repair and maintenance service",
            "ParentSectorId": 8
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 8,
        "Name": "Machinery",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 49,
            "Name": "Construction of metal structures",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 50,
            "Name": "Houses and buildings",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 51,
            "Name": "Metal products",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 52,
            "Name": "Metal works",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 53,
            "Name": "CNC-machining",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 54,
            "Name": "Forgings, Fasteners",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 55,
            "Name": "Gas, Plasma, Laser cutting",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 56,
            "Name": "MIG, TIG, Aluminum welding",
            "ParentSectorId": 9
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 9,
        "Name": "Metalworking",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 57,
            "Name": "Packaging",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 58,
            "Name": "Plastic goods",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 59,
            "Name": "Plastic processing technology",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 60,
            "Name": "Blowing",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 61,
            "Name": "Moulding",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 62,
            "Name": "Plastics welding and processing",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 63,
            "Name": "Plastic profiles",
            "ParentSectorId": 10
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 10,
        "Name": "Plastic and Rubber",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 64,
            "Name": "Advertising",
            "ParentSectorId": 11
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 65,
            "Name": "Book/Periodicals printing",
            "ParentSectorId": 11
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 66,
            "Name": "Labelling and packaging printing",
            "ParentSectorId": 11
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 11,
        "Name": "Printing",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 67,
            "Name": "Clothing",
            "ParentSectorId": 12
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 68,
            "Name": "Textile",
            "ParentSectorId": 12
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 12,
        "Name": "Textile and Clothing",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 69,
            "Name": "Other (Wood)",
            "ParentSectorId": 13
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 70,
            "Name": "Wooden building materials",
            "ParentSectorId": 13
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 71,
            "Name": "Wooden houses",
            "ParentSectorId": 13
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 13,
        "Name": "Wood",
        "ParentSectorId": 1
      }
    ],
    "Forms": [],
    "Parent": null,
    "SectorId": 1,
    "Name": "Manufacturing",
    "ParentSectorId": null
  },
  {
    "Children": [{
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 14,
        "Name": "Business Services",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 15,
        "Name": "Engineering",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 16,
        "Name": "Tourism",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 17,
        "Name": "Translation Services",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 72,
            "Name": "Data processing, Web portals, E-marketing",
            "ParentSectorId": 18
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 73,
            "Name": "Programming, Consultancy",
            "ParentSectorId": 18
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 74,
            "Name": "Software, Hardware",
            "ParentSectorId": 18
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 75,
            "Name": "Telecommunications",
            "ParentSectorId": 18
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 18,
        "Name": "Information Technology and Telecommunications",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      },
      {
        "Children": [{
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 76,
            "Name": "Air",
            "ParentSectorId": 19
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 77,
            "Name": "Rail",
            "ParentSectorId": 19
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 78,
            "Name": "Road",
            "ParentSectorId": 19
          },
          {
            "Children": [],
            "Forms": [],
            "SectorId": 79,
            "Name": "Water",
            "ParentSectorId": 19
          }
        ],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 19,
        "Name": "Transport and Logistics",
        "ParentSectorId": 2
      }
    ],
    "Forms": [],
    "Parent": null,
    "SectorId": 2,
    "Name": "Service",
    "ParentSectorId": null
  },
  {
    "Children": [{
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 20,
        "Name": "Creative Industries",
        "ParentSectorId": 3
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 21,
        "Name": "Energy technology",
        "ParentSectorId": 3
      },
      {
        "Children": [],
        "Forms": [],
        "SectorId": 22,
        "Name": "Environment",
        "ParentSectorId": 3
      }
    ],
    "Forms": [],
    "Parent": null,
    "SectorId": 3,
    "Name": "Other",
    "ParentSectorId": null
  }
];
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is, that the newList is not complete. It still has those initial 3, and it does not add any children to the list.

Comment: @EgertAia: Did you look at the update I made? As I noted, I missed that you were handling recursion incorrectly, and updated it accordingly. I also added a demo at the bottom. Click the `Show code snippet` arrow.

Comment: Im sorry. Did not notice that.
Wonderful answer. Apreciate that!